# MVC Form Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I am having trouble with my form validation.  I have a form class with the `Required` attribute on it and I have ClientValidationEnabled to true in my web.config.  I also have this call on my page `@{Html.EnableClientValidation();}`

I am using ajax form with the before submit option to catch the validation. Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: ensureValid
    };
    $('#applyForm').ajaxForm(options);
});

function ensureValid(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var result = $('#applyForm').validate();
    console.log(result.valid());
    return result.valid();
}
```

The code hits the ensureValid function but keeps continuing to the action in the controller even when I know a property should fire.

Thank you for any insight,

Brenna

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {` can be shortened to `$(function() ) {`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net-mvc-3, I would recommend at looking at using jquery.validate to perform your validation. It's far easier to setup, and generates cleaner code. You can see how to set this up [in my blog post](http://www.jasoncavett.com/2011/03/using-unobtrusive-jquery-validation.html) (I also cover a possible problem you could run into).